# wso2 esb inject few values after xslt transformation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am reading some values from source table and writing to a target table.Since the fields are different in names and some values , i am using XSLT mediator in WSO2 ESB.
After the xslt mediator , i want to inject few more values into the payload.Say some variables which i have previously store. I cant do it xslt because these values are in some variables.
So below is my code.What should be the code the dashed lines?

```
<enrich>
                <source clone="true" property="SOURCE_TABLE_PAYLOAD" type="property"/>
                <target type="body"/>
            </enrich>
            <xslt key="gov:/bcogc/transformation/SourcetoTargetTransformation.xslt"/>
            ----------------ADD SOME MORE VALUES HERE to the payload------------------
             <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:inserttotargettable"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="gov:/endpoints/INSERT_DataService_EP.xml"/>
            </call>
```

Please throw some lights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can again use an enrich mediator for example ,

```
<property name="orderID" scope="default" description="orderID">
            <orderID xmlns="">2</orderID>
 </property>
  <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="$ctx:orderID"/>
            <target action="sibling" xpath="//orders"/>
  </enrich>
```

Here the orderID property is defined , so now you can add that property as a sibling with you request coming out of XSLT, so the request will look like below after enriching

```
<orders>
 <order>
  <price>50.00</price>
  <quantity>500</quantity>
  <symbol>IBM</symbol>
  <comment>REF 10053</comment>
 </order>
 <order>
  <price>18.00</price>
  <quantity>500</quantity>
  <symbol>MSFT</symbol>
  <comment>ref 20088398289</comment>
 </order> 
</orders>
<orderID>2</OrderID>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do a i replace value of one tag which is already existing? May be price or quantity>